# Iferror formula wont work cause of the "" in the replace arguement, nothing is working

Tags: vba, excel

I copied precisely the codes from MSDN:
[sample-user-defined-function-to-hide-formula-errors-in-excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/280094/sample-user-defined-function-to-hide-formula-errors-in-excel)

The formula I'm trying to put in a range of cells is:

```
  Selection = "=IFError(INDEX(Data_Import!$B$2:$R$16, MATCH(Reg!$B4,     
   Data_Import!$A$2:$A$16,0),Reg!C$3), "n/a" )"
```

But I am getting an error message in the syntax

> Compile error:
>
> Expected: end of statement

what am I doing wrong?

my sub code is:

```
Sub PresentDat(Wks As Integer)
Dim x, LenWks As Long
Dim Y As Variant
Worksheets(5).Activate
    Range("B26").CurrentRegion.Select
        x = Selection.Columns.Count - 1
Worksheets(Wks).Activate
    Sheets(Wks).UsedRange.Find("Element").Select
        LenWks = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Rows _
            .Count - 1 Selection.Offset(1, 1).Resize(LenWks, x).Select
Selection.Formula = "=INDEX(Data_Import!$A$1:$R$65,     
MATCH($B23,Data_Import!$A$1:$A$65,0), COLUMN(C23)-1)"
    Sheets(Wks).UsedRange.Find("No.").Select
        LenWks = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Rows _
            .Count - 4
Selection.Offset(1, 1).Resize(LenWks, x).Select
Selection = "=IFError(INDEX(Data_Import!$B$2:$R$16, MATCH(Reg!$B4, Data_Import!$A$2:$A$16,0),Reg!C$3), )"

End Sub
```

I just can't get it to put in the error message I want in the cells, :c . .
Thanks!

Comment: by "replace" I am referring to the second arguement of the "iferror" worksheet function: iferror( function, replace with if the error happens)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of the top formula shown you need to escape the inner "" with "" so the entire formula doesn't thrown an error i.e.  `""n/a""`

```
= "=IFError(INDEX(Data_Import!$B$2:$R$16, MATCH(Reg!$B4,Data_Import!$A$2:$A$16,0),Reg!C$3), ""n/a"")"
```

Comment: trying now... OMG YOU ARE A GENIUS! this worked, ty so much! So, if you need to place " " in side a string you just double it up? "" "" Nice.

Comment: I'm still kinda a noob with a "Excel 2016 Power Programming with VBA" book ;) but sometimes google + book = no answers :C

Comment: fwiw, you can avoid doubling up double quotes (e.g. `""` or an empty string) within a quoted string by using `TEXT(,)`. In other words, replace `""""` with `TEXT(,)`.

Comment: @Jeeped I did not know that. I will be adding that to the armoury.